# Mutate dataframe and carry out partial string match

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose you have a string-heavy dataframe:

```
     x <- data.frame(name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie"),
                    prod = c("Hard Hat", "Goggles", "Bus Fare", "Goggles", "Training", "Hard Hat, Laptop"))
```

How can you add a mutated column (let's call it `category`) to this dataframe to categorise the data based on some arbitrary criteria. For example how can I set `x$category` to equal "PPE" if the word 'Hard Hat' or 'Goggles' appears in `x$prod` but equal "IT" if the word 'Laptop' appears in `x$prod`?

In addition, I would like the matching to also handle partial matches and different cases, if possible. For example, 'Bus Fare' could also be input as (non-exhaustive list) 'Bus Ticket', or 'BUS FARE' or 'Bus TICKET'; in either case, I'd need to categorize it as 'Transport' as the word 'Bus' will be present.

Expected output:

```
    name     prod  category
1   Alice Hard Hat       PPE
2   Alice  Goggles       PPE
3   Alice Bus Fare TRANSPORT
4     Bob  Goggles       PPE
5     Bob Training  TRAINING
6 Charlie   Laptop        IT
```

I would ideally like to solve this within `tidyverse` and I think it will require a combination of `mutate()` and various `stringr` functions but I can't quite figure out the exact workflow I will require.

Comment: how long is the list of unique products? It is it small, `case_when` and `str_detect` will do the trick. If the list of unique products is long, you probably want another strategy.

Comment: Good question. The data I'm applying this to is around 2,000 rows long and the number of unique products (unique in terms of a unique`x$prod` string) is large....at about 2,000 long! (Sadly the dev who wrote the code to generate the data decided to concat all the products and cost into a single string!). A lot of my work has been getting the products separated into a clean list. From here, I think partial string matching will be most useful to catch 99% of edge cases and categorise appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your situation, you will probably need to create a vector of keywords for each category and use `str_detect` using concatenated `|` statements:

```
x <- data.frame(name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie"),
                prod = c("Hard Hat", "Goggles", "Bus Fare", "Goggles", "Training", "Hard Hat, Laptop"))


transport <- c("bus")
ppe <- c("goggles", "hard hat")
tech <- c("laptop")
training <- c("training")

x <- x %>% 
  mutate(
    category = 
      case_when(
        str_detect(tolower(prod), paste(transport, collapse = "|")) ~ "TRANSPORT",
        str_detect(tolower(prod), paste(ppe, collapse = "|")) ~ "PPE",
        str_detect(tolower(prod), paste(tech, collapse = "|")) ~ "IT",
        str_detect(tolower(prod), paste(training, collapse = "|")) ~ "TRAINING",
      )
  )
```

#### Result:

```
> x
     name             prod  category
1   Alice         Hard Hat       PPE
2   Alice          Goggles       PPE
3   Alice         Bus Fare TRANSPORT
4     Bob          Goggles       PPE
5     Bob         Training  TRAINING
6 Charlie Hard Hat, Laptop       PPE
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I think the keywords list is the key here. It's going to be a pain to put the list together in the first instance but I'm going to have to suck it up!